# How to convert trained PyTorch model to Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

I am aware of ONNX package but I am not sure how to use it here. The tutorial on their Github page helps convert to Tensorflow but I want to convert it to Keras! 
Any help would be appreciated.